# SQL Server auto increment/math issue special

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is the entityRelationship diagram of the 5 tables i am working with:

[image]

and here is some example data of what i want to achieve:

```
tblController           
ControllerID    ControllerName      
     1           Controller 1       
     2           Controller 2       

tblControllerLine           
ControllerLineID    ControllerID        
       1                 1                  

tblDevice           
DeviceID    DeviceName      
   1         Device 1       
   2         Device 2       

tblDeviceLine           
DeviceLineID    DeviceID    ControllerLineID    Address
     1             1               1             1101
     2             2               1             1201


tblPointLine            
PointLineID DeviceLineID    InputType   Address
     1           1           Output      1101
     2           1           Output      1102
     3           1           Output      1103
     4           1           Output      1104
     5           1           Output      1105
     6           1           Output      1106
     7           1           Output      1107
     8           1           Output      1108
     9           2           Output      1201
     10          2           Output      1202
     11          2           Output      1203
     12          2           Output      1204
     13          2           Input       1201
     14          2           Input       1202
     15          2           Input       1203
     16          2           Input       1204
```

How this works:

1. The user selects a Controller and adds it to the ControllerLine
2. The user selects a Device to add to the Controller on the ControllerLine. This is then added to the DeviceLine and assigned an address
3. The user adds a Point to the Device which is addressed based on the Device selected. This is added to the PointLine table.

Now my problem is the auto incrementation or mathematical calculation required to address Device 2. This SQL Statement would solve the tblDeviceLine address and the tblPointLine address for Device 1, BUT NOT Device 2:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ControllerLineID ORDER BY ModuleLineID) AS NewVariation
FROM   ModuleLine
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    Address = (NewVariation * 100) + 1001
```

Now as you can see when a 2nd Device is added, it is given and address of 1201 (100 greater each time an additional device is added) This is why on the PointLine, that the next set of 8 Points have an address starting at 1201 - 1204.

Now based on the InputType, whether or not its Input or Output, i need this auto increment to take that into account aswell as the DeviceLineID and PointLineID. so this is why 1201-1204 appears twice.

Does anyone have any ideas if this is possible to have this kind of auto increment in SQL?

essentially i need to change the (NewVariation)

- so it increments by 100, not 1 for the Controller
- so it increments by 1 for the Device 1, and then 100 when the ControllerLineID changes

Thanks for any help, and I hope this is easier to understand

Comment: Couldn't you just add 1100 to the row_number if you need it to start at 1101?

Comment: that would work for Device 1 thankyou, any ideas about Device 2?

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and still didn't figure out what you want to happen and why. Is it me or you?

Comment: tried explaining it better at the bottom, hope this helps

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one, so help us to help you. Please provide the DDL of the tables involved, some sample data, and expected result.

Comment: please give me 5 - 10 minutes and ill reword it

Comment: I'll give the the hold day if you need, it's your question... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best answer by far but it does what I need, i would really appreciate if anyone could make it a lot simpler:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------CONTROLLER LINE COUNT--------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ControlBoardID ORDER BY ControllerLineID) AS NewVariation
    FROM   ControllerLine
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    ControllerCount = NewVariation 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------UPDATE COUNTER IN DEVICE----------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE DeviceLine set DeviceCount = ControllerCount 
FROM ControllerLine
Where DeviceLine.ControllerLineID = ControllerLine.ControllerLineID  

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------DEVICE LINE CONTROLLER COUNT--------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ControllerLineID ORDER BY DeviceLineID) AS NewVariation
    FROM   DeviceLine
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    Address = (DeviceCount*1000) + (NewVariation * 100) + 1
```

based on the question above I have added a count column in both the ControllerLine table and DeviceLine table, this gives me the ability to start the variation from scratch for every ControlBoard they connect to as an example.